# Calling bash function from a bash function which takes arguments like any other language?

Tags: bash

I am new to bash scripting and trying to find a way to call a bash function from another bash function that takes one or many arguments passed like we have in other languages ?

for example.

```
function b()
{
    echo "$1 World!"
}

function a()
{
    b("Hello!")
}
```

with call for function "a" would give output of Hello World! (I am not sure if this will work). Any help is appreciated.

Thank  you

Comment: Start with searching the manual for "function" if you are new. There is no need to ask such trivial questions.

Answer (score -1):

Just add the parameters after the function call, separated by white space (Just like the parameters of a main function in a C or Java binary).

The following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function b()
{
    echo "$1 World!"
}

function a()
{
    b "Hello!"
}

a
```

will output `Hello! World!`.

Surround the parameter with double-quotes if needed.

example:

```
$ b x y
x World!
$ b "x y"
x y World!
```